# Como ingreso una pregunta dentro de un input en python

Tags: python, input

Buen día.
Estoy aprendiendo Python y de tarea tengo que hacer un programa que me calcule el salario de un trabajador, pero no tengo claro como poner una pregunta dentro de un input, es decir:

```py
bonificación = input("Si tiene bonificaciones ingrese 1: ") 
#y aquí debería ir si no tiene bonificaciones poner 0.
```

Gracias! :)

Comment: Así como lo tienes esta bien, solo que a como se ve en tu ejemplo vas a recibir un int, por lo que deberias ponerlo asi `int(input("Si tiene bonificaciones ingrese 1: "))`

Comment: Por defecto en Python3, 'input' devuelve una cadena o String. Para indicarle que quieres que lo interprete como un número entero usa el código que te ha puesto Jaime

Comment: @Fran Input SIEMPRE devuelve una cadena. Lo que haces al poner int(input()) es decirle a Python que convierta esa cadena en entero. NO decirle a Python que lo interprete de x modo.

Answer (score 0):

Primero, cuidado como definís una variable. evita las acentuaciones `` ` `` y `ñ`
Segundo, lo que podes hacer es validar el ingreso del usuario:

```
bonificacion = input("Si tiene bonificaciones ingrese <si/no>: ") 
while not (bonificacion.isalpha() and bonificacion =='si' or bonificacion =='no'):
    bonificacion = input('Ingresaste una respuesta invalida <si/no>: ')

if bonificacion == 'si':
    #codigo tuyo con respecto
    pass
elif bonificacion == 'no':
    bonificacion = 0 
    #codigo tuyo
```

Comment: para versiones mas actuales de Python se puede usar el operador morsa `:=`

Answer (score 0):

Aquí se me plantean dos opciones:

1. Tienes que hacer cosas diferentes con cada opción
2. Quieres solo el valor numérico (1 o 0) para hacer operaciones con él

#### opción 1

```
bonificacion = ''   # Aquí guardarás la respuesta
while not bonificacion in ['0', '1']:   #   Mientras no sea una opción válida repites
    bonificacion = input('Tienes bonificaciones (0 = "no" / 1 = "sí"')
    if bonificacion == '0':
        #   Código para esta opción
        print('Aceptaste opción 0 (No hay bonif.)')
    if bonificacion == '1':
        #   Código para esta opción
        print('Aceptaste opción 1 (Sí hay bonif.)')

#   Sigues con el programa
bonificacion = int(bonificacion)    #   Si quieres pasarlo a número
```

#### opción 2

```
bonificacion = ''
while not bonificacion in ['0', '1']:
    bonificacion = input('Tienes bonificaciones (0 = "no" / 1 = "sí"')

bonificacion = int(bonificacion)    #   Para pasarlo a número
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Tomy!! La opcion 1 era lo que estaba buscando.